# Struct inheritance in MIDL

Tags: inheritance, struct, idl, midl

I am trying to inherit from and extend a structure defined in MIDL. I used the same syntax as for interface inheritance i.e

```
typedef struct stDBIBinVarDataEx
 {
   float x;
 } MYSTRUCT ;

struct struct2 : MYSTRUCT
 {
   float y;
 };
```

but the compiler generates errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. MIDL isn't a C++ compiler.

You CAN declare struct2 as containing MYSTRUCT:

```
struct struct2
{
    MYSTRUCT mystruct;
    float y;
}
```

It's not quite the same thing but it's probably as close as you're going to get.

Comment: This approach may come handy but is problematic when you want to pass more specialized structures to interfaces, e.g. `Bar([in] MYSTRUCT s);` cannot be called with an `struct2`-instance (obviously).